# Get the color needed to be composed with another one to get a target color in swift

Tags: swift, colors, core-graphics

I use an `NSTableView` to draw some information in `NSTableCellView(s)`. I want to set the background color of the `NSTableView` to a certain value and the `NSTableCellView's` background color to another value independently of the alpha component of the colors used. The problem is that if I set a background color with alpha component 0.3 to `NSTableCellView`, we see the background color of the `NSTableView` and then the color is not what I set.

I see two options to solve this problem:

1. draw the background color of the `NSTableView` without drawing under the rects used by the `NSTableCellView(s)`.
2. use color theory and CoreGraphics to compute the new color.

I have worked around a bit option 1 and haven't got any result. I am now looking more into option 2.

For example, if I have two colors:

```
let tableViewBackgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 48/255, green: 47/255, blue: 46/255, alpha: 1)

let tableViewCellBackgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 42/255, green: 41/255, blue: 40/255, alpha: 1)
```

I want, that the resulting color applied to NSTableCellView background:

```
let targetColor = tableViewCellBackgroundColor.withAplphaComponent(0.3)
```

even when the color:

```
let tableViewBackgroundColorWithAlpha = tableViewBackgroundColor.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

is applied to the background of the NSTableView.

I am looking for an extension to NSColor (CGColor would work) like this:

```
extension NSColor {

    ///
    /// Return the color that needs to be composed with the color parameter 
    /// in order to result in the current (self) color.
    ///
    func composedColor(with color: NSColor) -> NSColor

}
```

That could be used like this:

```
let color = targetColor.composedColor(with: 
tableViewBackgroundColorWithAlpha)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the solution for this problem has finally been to avoid drawing the parts with table view cells (option 1 on the question). I inspired myself from [Drawing Custom Alternating Row Backgrounds in `NSTableViews` with Swift](https://christiantietze.de/posts/2017/05/draw-alternating-table-view-rows/) to implement the final solution.

It basically involve overriding the method `func drawBackground(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect)` of the `NSTableView` but avoiding drawing the background part of the table where there is cells present.

Here is the solution:

```
override func drawBackground(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect) {

    super.drawBackground(inClipRect: clipRect)

    drawTopBackground(inClipRect: clipRect)
    drawBottomBackground(inClipRect: clipRect)
}

private func drawTopBackground(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect) {

    guard clipRect.origin.y < 0 else { return }

    let rectHeight = rowHeight + intercellSpacing.height
    let minY = NSMinY(clipRect)
    var row = 0
    currentBackgroundColor.setFill()

    while true {

        let rowRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: (rectHeight * CGFloat(row) - rectHeight), width: NSMaxX(clipRect), height: rectHeight)

        if self.rows(in: rowRect).isEmpty {
            rowRect.fill()
        }
        if rowRect.origin.y < minY { break }
        row -= 1
    }
}

private func drawBottomBackground(inClipRect clipRect: NSRect) {

    let rectHeight = rowHeight + intercellSpacing.height
    let maxY = NSMaxY(clipRect)
    var row = rows(in: clipRect).location
    currentBackgroundColor.setFill()

    while true {

        let rowRect = NSRect(
            x: 0,
            y: (rectHeight * CGFloat(row)),
            width: NSMaxX(clipRect),
            height: rectHeight)

        if self.rows(in: rowRect).isEmpty {
            rowRect.fill()
        }
        if rowRect.origin.y > maxY { break }
        row += 1
    }
}
```